# lxml parse html returns empty result while beautifulsoup returns reasonable parsed

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, lxml

I do understand that traditionally they are saying that lxml are stricter than BeautifulSoup, however, what I do not get is the following:

(Basically I am requesting a web page, in Chinese, and expecting to select some span. Similar pages can work without error but for some links lxml just cannot parse)

```
In [1]: headers = {'User-Agent': ''}

In [2]: url = 'http://basic.10jqka.com.cn/600219/company.html'

In [3]: headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0'}

In [6]: import lxml.html

In [7]: res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

In [8]: tree = lxml.html.fromstring(res.content)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b512dc78ed68> in <module>()
----> 1 tree = lxml.html.fromstring(res.content)

/home/jgu/repos/.venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py in fromstring(html, base_url, parser, **kw)
    874     else:
    875         is_full_html = _looks_like_full_html_unicode(html)
--> 876     doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
    877     if is_full_html:
    878         return doc

/home/jgu/repos/.venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py in document_fromstring(html, parser, ensure_head_body, **kw)
    763     if value is None:
    764         raise etree.ParserError(
--> 765             'Document is empty')
    766     if ensure_head_body and value.find('head') is None:
    767         value.insert(0, Element('head'))

ParserError: Document is empty

In [12]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [13]: soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

In [14]: soup.title
Out[14]: <title>南山铝业(600219) 公司资料_F10_同花顺金融服务网</title>

In [15]: sel_query = (
    ...:     '#detail > div.bd > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > '
    ...:     'td:nth-of-type(2) > span'
    ...: )

In [16]: soup.select(sel_query)
Out[16]: [<span>山东南山铝业股份有限公司</span>]

In [17]: soup.select(sel_query)[0].text
Out[17]: '山东南山铝业股份有限公司'
```

As I have said, links like http://basic.10jqka.com.cn/600000/company.html does work.

So I can fall back to bs4 when the parse result is empty, but I want to understand why lxml just fails to parse a reasonable dom tree out of the source. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `fromstring` function from `lxml.html` need a [string type variable](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html). And `response.content` return a [bytes](http://docs.python-requests.org/zh_CN/latest/user/quickstart.html#id4). Use `response.text` will be right.

For `BeautifulSoup`, the constructor of it accept [a string or a file-like object](https://github.com/waylan/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/__init__.py).

Comment: Did  you mean some pages  work on both parsers and some pages only work on `bs`?

Comment: yes. many links lxml just work but it fails for some example and return none